# conda init doesn't initialize shell?

Tags: cluster-computing, conda, miniconda

I'm trying to activate a conda environment on a cluster. However, I keep being returned with the shell needing to be initialized. Ruuning `conda init bash` does nothing and even when closing the shell and trying again I get the same 'conda is not initialized'?

```
-bash-4.2$ conda activate libraries/

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.

-bash-4.2$ conda init bash
no change     /usr/local/miniconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /usr/local/miniconda3/bin/conda
no change     /usr/local/miniconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /usr/local/miniconda3/bin/activate
no change     /usr/local/miniconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /usr/local/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /usr/local/miniconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /usr/local/miniconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /usr/local/miniconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /usr/local/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /usr/local/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /nethome/6966225/.bashrc
No action taken.
-bash-4.2$ conda activate libraries/

CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run
```

Answer (score 5):

The lack of changes is likely because you previously already ran `conda init` and the changes have been made already - that is, Conda will only show this if it finds the initialization code is present. Have a look at your `~/.bashrc` file to check if there is a Conda initialization section.

The `conda init` command only updates the shell initialization files (e.g., `.bashrc`) to include shell function setup. One still needs to source the relevant initialization file. Typically, this is done by restarting the shell session or running `. ~/.bashrc`.

Be aware that the shell also needs to be launched in a way that it loads the relevant initialization file. Most user-initiated shell sessions do this automatically, but in some situations one may need to explicitly include a flag for interactive (`-i` in bash) or login (`-l` in bash) sessions to ensure loading of `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` files.